# Get the day of the last Friday of each month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new with ruby and I want to get the day of the last Friday of each month.
For example, the last Friday of March is 29, the Last Friday of April 26.
So, how can I get a solution? 
I'm using the rails framework.

The method `.cweek` returns the week of the year, but does not return the week of the current month.

Comment: @sawa I guess his example refers to the current year...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'date'

(1..12).each do |month|
  d = Date.new(2013, month, -1)
  d -= (d.wday - 5) % 7
  puts d
end
```

[Source](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Last_Friday_of_Each_Month#Ruby) (second/third Google result..)

Comment: `d = Date.new(2013, month, -1)` also gives the last day of the month.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with Lee's answer, I'm only posting this one because (I thought) it's pretty cool.

Using gem `Chronic` (https://github.com/mojombo/chronic):

```
#Last Friday of this coming December
require 'chronic'
last_friday = Chronic.parse("First Friday of next January") - 1.week
```

Comment: You'd think I'd be the first to suggest Chronic too (I maintain it), it definitely has it's place. I don't think that's here but certainly an option none-the-less.

Answer (score 3):

Retrieving the last friday of a month can be made in a single line:

```
def last_fridays_for_every_month_of_year(year)
  (1..12).map do |month|
    Date.new(year, month, -1).downto(0).find(&:friday?)
  end
end
```

You may use it like this:

```
last_fridays_for_every_month_of_year 2013
#=> [#<Date: 2013-01-25 ((2456318j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-02-22 ((2456346j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-03-29 ((2456381j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-04-26 ((2456409j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-05-31 ((2456444j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-06-28 ((2456472j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-07-26 ((2456500j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-08-30 ((2456535j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-09-27 ((2456563j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-10-25 ((2456591j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-11-29 ((2456626j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     #<Date: 2013-12-27 ((2456654j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

Comment: Hi @tessi, do you mind explaining what the `.find(&friday?)` fragment do? I can't seem to find related documentation on that.

Comment: @vincentleest sure. `Date.new(year, month, -1).downto(0)` gives you an array of dates. the find-part is equal to `date_array.find {|d| d.friday?}`. It returns the first date for which `date.friday?` returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
require "active_support/core_ext"

end_of_month = Date.today.end_of_month
if end_of_month - end_of_month.beginning_of_week >= 4
   end_of_month+5.days
else
   end_of_month-2.days
end
# => Fri, 29 Mar 2013
```

Comment: your script give Thu, 04 Apr 2013 in my ruby console

Comment: Sorry, I had the weekday count from 1. I fixed it.